# How to erase an element from std::vector when using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a rather simple templated class in which I store items in a vector. However, I get the following error when I try to erase an element:

```
C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type
      'TestComponent' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class ComponentManager {
    ComponentManager() {};
    ~ComponentManager() {};

    T* newComponent() {
        components.emplace_back(T());
        return &components.back();
    }

    // This is the method I'm having trouble with
    void destroyComponent(T* t) {
        components.erase(std::remove(components.begin(), components.end(), *t), components.end());
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> components;
};
```

---

Yes, I know this can lead to invalidated pointers and whatnot. No need to go there.

Comment: Does `TestComponent` have an `operator ==` defined?

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't. I'd like to try not to require it since the generic type could be just about anything. I'm probably just formulating the removal wrong.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, you don't have to write `emplace_back(T())`, you can just write `emplace_back()`

Comment: @manabreak In order to remove something you need to check if they are equal.  You need to use `remove_if` if you want to supply a way to compare two objects.

Comment: Why using raw pointers instead of references ?

Comment: FYI, `emplace_back` can invalidate all your pointers if it forces the vector's `size` to grow beyond its `capacity`, meaning that all your pointers are now garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to erase *by pointer* you need to use the right algorithm for that. `std::remove` does equality comparison amongst the elements. Based on your comments, you don't want to require that, so you may prefer [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead:

```
void destroyComponent(T* t) {
    components.erase(
        std::remove_if(components.begin(), components.end(), [t](const T& comp) {
            return &comp == t;
        }),
        components.end()
    );
}
```

---

Note that it's not particularly safe to hold onto pointers into a `vector` since inserting into a vector could cause a reallocation, which would invalidate all the previously held pointers. You may want to consider a different container (or just have a `vector<T*>` or, even better, `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`).

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for! Didn't know about `remove_if`until just now. Will accept as soon as the timer let's me. :)

Comment: @mana the part at the bottom is the important part.  The `T*` you are getting out can be invalidated the next time an element is added to the vector.  Your design is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove` searches the given sequence, defined by the beginning and the ending iterator, for the given values, specified as the third parameter. The value's type must, obviously, implement the equality comparison operator, in order for `std::remove` to compare the values in the sequence with the given value.

Your `TestComponent` class does not implement the `==` operator, as the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your solution is dangerous: looks like you keep pointers of objects that stored inside a `std::vector` and unless you reserve enough room in advance you are going to get a dangling pointers when you add new elements. If you are reserving enough room you probably should remove object by pointer rather than by value:

```
components.erase(std::remove_if(components.begin(), components.end(), [t]( const T &tc ) { return &tc == t; } ), components.end());
```

unless you can uniquely identify object by value and then you need to implement proper `operator==` for that class.

I would recommend to store `TestComponent` with `std::unique_ptr` then you will not have issue with memory reallocation by `std::vector` and your remove will work as intended without implementing `operator==`

```
template<class T>
class ComponentManager {
    ComponentManager() {};
    ~ComponentManager() {};

     template< class... Args >
     T *newComponent( Args...&& args ) {
        components.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        return components.back().get();
    }

    // This is the method I'm having trouble with
    void destroyComponent(T* t) {
        components.erase(std::remove(components.begin(), components.end(), t), components.end());
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>> components;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, this is just some toy code I'm dabbling with. :)

Comment: @manabreak does not really matter, as you use pointer to object inside `vector` your next question is going to be: why my program crash when I use that pointers.

Comment: No it's not. I ensure the capacity is large enough for my needs and won't do resizes.

Comment: @manabreak IMHO terrible solution, sooner or later you hit that limit. You should at least check  reserved size in `newComponent` code to prevent reallocation.

Comment: This gets heavily off-railed and has nothing to do with the original question, no matter how terrible solution it is.

Comment: @manabreak disagree, if you implement it properly your original question will disappear, look into solution with `std::unique_ptr`